# How to convert SELECT ARRAY(column) to Criteria Query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-query

I am using Criteria Query in my project. I have to the following SQL query

`SELECT ARRAY(column_name) from table`

I need to write this in Hibernate Criteria query. The current Criteria query code I am using is as follows

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Class> cq = cb.createQuery(Class.class);
Root<Class1> root = cq.from(Class1.class);
cq.select(root);
return getSession().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Instead of *cq.select(root)* I need to have *cq.select(array(column))*. I have tried Tuple and Multiselect both did not work.